# Where is the configuration information of installed packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I install something via `pip`, where is the information about the installed package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
pip show <package name>
```

To list installed packages:

```
pip list
```

And of course most importantly:

```
pip help
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip show <package name>
```

The above command displays the Location. The path is usually under `/usr/lib/python<m.n>/dist-packages/`